# How do I stop a bouncy JQuery animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, sliding

In a webapp I'm working on, I want to create some *slider* `div`s that will move up and down with mouseover & mouseout (respectively.) I currently have it implemented with JQuery's `hover()` function, by using `animate()` and reducing/increasing it's `top` css value as needed. This works fairly well, actually.

The problem is that it tends to get stuck. If you move the mouse over it (especially near the bottom), and quickly remove it, it will slide up & down continuously and won't stop until it's completed 3-5 cycles. To me, it seems that the issue might have to do with one animation starting before another is done (e.g. the two are trying to run, so they slide back and forth.)

Okay, now for the code. Here's the basic JQuery that I'm using:

```
$('.slider').hover(
    /* mouseover */
    function(){
        $(this).animate({
            top : '-=120'
        }, 300);
    },
    /* mouseout*/
    function(){
        $(this).animate({
            top : '+=120'
        }, 300);
    }
);
```

I've also recreated the behavior in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W5EsJ/7/).

Any ideas on what's going on? :)

==EDIT== UPDATED JSFiddle

Comment: It seems to only slide up and down once for me when I remove it quickly in the fiddle

Comment: When you hover over innerContent, it moves up, thus making it no longer under the mouse, firing the mouseleave event causing it to animate back to it's original position. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Kevin, the problem he is stating is that sometimes when you move the mouse over the slider only once, the animation performs multiple cycles i.e., going up and down multiple times.

Comment: @sv_in Right, but that is caused by the div animating out from under the mouse, triggering the leave event, which in turn triggers the enter event yet again when it animates back down, and then the leave yet again, causing a loop.

Comment: @KevinB You're right. In the actual implementation though, the `div` has a `height` large enough that a mouseleave won't be triggered. I've updated the JSFiddle to reflect this.

Comment: Try this, all I added was `.stop(true,true)` to prevent the animation queue from becoming backed up. http://jsfiddle.net/W5EsJ/18/

Comment: @KevinB If you quickly bring in the hover from the bottom up, it sometimes will move back and forth so fast it flashes.

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do about it. By making that mouse action, you are repeatedly hovering over and out of the div, jQuery's action in this case makes sense.

Comment: @KevinB Alright then. While not as spectacular as I would have liked, your idea works well, and is the only suggestion that doesn't cause the `div` to slide out of view. If you'd post it as answer, I'd be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: See my updated answer, i solved the flicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't perfect, but adding `.stop(true,true)` will prevent most of what you are seeing.

http://jsfiddle.net/W5EsJ/18/

If you hover from bottom up quickly, it will still flicker because you are moving your mouse out of the div causing the mouseout event to fire, animating the div back down.

You can lessen the flicker by reducing the delay, however it will still be present until the delay is 0 (no animation)

**Update**

I thought about it and realized that there is an obvious solution to this. Hoverintent-like functionality!

http://jsfiddle.net/W5EsJ/20/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer;
    $('.slider').hover(
        /* mouseover */
        function(){
            var self = this;
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                $(self).stop(true,true).animate({
                    top : '-=120'
                }, 300).addClass('visible');
            },150)
        },
        /* mouseout*/
        function(){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $(this).filter(".visible").stop(true,true).animate({
                top : '+=120'
            }, 300).removeClass("visible");
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Awesome! I just wish I could +1 it a bit more. Anyways, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [.stop()](http://jqapi.com/#p=stop) and also use the outer container position

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider').hover(
        /* mouseover */
        function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({
                    top : $('.outer').position().top
            }, 300);
        },
        /* mouseout*/
        function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({
                top : $('.outer').position().top + 120
            }, 300);
        }
    );
});
​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/W5EsJ/19/)**

Hope this helps

Comment: In your demo it seems to have fixed the bounce issue, but it tends to slide out of view... :P

Comment: updated the demo. noticed that slider position is relative, so used outer container's position, might help for the current situation

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't reproduce your issue but I believe that `hover` is getting called multiple times. To work around this you can check if the div is already in animation. If yes, then don't run another animation again.

Add following piece of code to check if the div is already 'animating':

```
if ($(this).is(':animated')) {
   return;
}
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/W5EsJ/2/
Reference:http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/

Comment: It seems to animate out of view in your fiddle

Answer (score 1):

I understand the problem and reproduced it, it happens when hovering from the bottom up. The hovering with the mouse is what's causing the problem since the animation function will be called when the mouse hovers over the image. You need to control what happens here by using mouse enter and mouse leave, check out a similar example: [Jquery Animate on Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747039/jquery-animate-on-hover)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's like that is because the hover is getting queued up causing it to slide up and down multiple times.  There's a plug-in called hoverIntent which fixes the issue.  http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

If you do decide to use hoverIntent, the only thing you have to change in your code is .hover > .hoverIntent