# jquery pass a custom function to click event does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

This may be a stupid question but I'd like to get some clarification on the matter. I have a function that loops through an array and copies values from input A to input AA (B to BB, and so on). But I want this function to execute when a hidden div is visible only. So I was trying to do this:

```
$('#showSave').on('click', function () {
    copyInputValues();
    $('#divModal').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Then I also tried this to no avail:

```
$('#showSave').click(copyInputValues);
```

This is my custom function:

```
function copyInputValues() {
    var minInputs = ['abel1', 'abel2', 'abel3', 'abel4'];
    $.each(minInputs, function (i, val) {
        $('#l' + val).change(function () {
            $('#modalL' + val).val($(this).val());
        });
    });
}
```

What is wrong with these scripts? I'm not very versed on javascript or jquery. I'm kinda learning and I've found stackOverflow to be a great source of information.
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: What I understand is you only need to select visible divs? Try this selector if so. `$('#showSave:visible')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Animate on Hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747039/jquery-animate-on-hover)

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
if ($('#divModal').css('display') == 'block') {
   copyInputValues(); 
}
```

OR

```
if (!$("#divModal").css('visibility') === 'hidden') {
    copyInputValues(); 
}
```

OR

```
if($('#divModal').is(':visible')) {
    copyInputValues(); 
}
```