# Triggering css animation with Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have been reading for hours how to trigger a css element with jquery. I have read many forums on here but nothing is working for me. I am new to coding and trying to do something simple in jquery but cannot figure it out.

Here is my HTML:

```
<h1 class="Header">
        Hello!<div class="wave animate"> </div> 
    </h1>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.wave {
 animation-name: wave-animation;
 animation-duration: 2.5s;
 transform-origin: 70% 70%;
 display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes wave-animation {
  0% { transform: rotate( 0.0deg) }
 10% { transform: rotate(14.0deg) } 
 20% { transform: rotate(-8.0deg) }
 30% { transform: rotate(14.0deg) }
 40% { transform: rotate(-4.0deg) }
 50% { transform: rotate(10.0deg) }
 60% { transform: rotate( 0.0deg) }
100% { transform: rotate( 0.0deg) }
}
```

I have animated the wave and want to have the animation triggered with a hover. I know this can easily be done in css but am trying for the life of me to do it in java/jquery.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I feel like I have tried every viable option I have read about. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747039/jquery-animate-on-hover?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery Animate on Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747039/jquery-animate-on-hover)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is not needed here. Just use :hover in your css.

```css
.wave {
 display: inline-block;
}
.wave:hover{
 animation-name: wave-animation;
 animation-duration: 2.5s;
 transform-origin: 70% 70%;
}

@keyframes wave-animation {
  0% { transform: rotate( 0.0deg) }
 10% { transform: rotate(14.0deg) } 
 20% { transform: rotate(-8.0deg) }
 30% { transform: rotate(14.0deg) }
 40% { transform: rotate(-4.0deg) }
 50% { transform: rotate(10.0deg) }
 60% { transform: rotate( 0.0deg) }
100% { transform: rotate( 0.0deg) }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="Header">
        Hello!<div class="wave animate"> </div> 
    </h1>
```